# JFrog artifactory remote repository artifacts

Tags: artifactory, remote-repository

JFrog artifactory sees the tree of the remote repository, but does not see its artifacts.

A setting "Store Artifacts Locally" in the Advanced Remote Repositories Settings is selected.

Comment: Which type of repository (npm, maven, docker etc.)?

Comment: @DrorBereznitsky maven repo

Comment: most Maven repositories should support remote browsing. Which remote repository are you proxying?

Comment: @DrorBereznitsky I use nexus repository

Answer (score 0):

"Store Artifacts Locally" if enabled, when ever you download an artifact from the remote repository it will cache a local copy. Next time when you request the same artifact, it will serve it from the cache. Only after caching you can browse it in UI.